# Multiple ALSA sound stream in Embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, embedded, alsa

Currently In my embedded linux I can not open multiple ALSA sound stream. What I need is to have different sound playing at a time. Like one application is playing video and other playing some wav file at a same time.

Thanks,
  Sunny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is dmix enabled? If it is not possible, you need a software mixing daemon, like pulseaudio.

Comment: Isn't dmix a software mixing daemon? Anyway, this is basically correct, you need a mixer.

Comment: It's not a separate daemon, it's part of the ALSA library, and ALSA handles running it in one of the clients that has the device open.

Comment: DMix is not enabled, I have some information about it but I haven't heard about pulseaudio. Thanks.